# How to keep audio playing when switching users in Windows?

Tags: winapi, audio, windows-users

It seems that Windows automatically stops my audio play when switching to another user. Is there any way where I can keep audio playing when windows switch to another user?

Comment: How are you playing the audio to begin with? There are many different multimedia APIs available for Windows. Chances are, I'm guessing you are playing the audio from a user mode app that is being suspended when switching users. You may need to play the audio from a background service instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Currently I'm using MATLAB's audio play functions because the main body of my project is on MATLAB. However, MATLAB also supports calls out of its framework, e.g., Windows APIs. So any recommendations?